# Swift: Add Action to a Table View Cell when value entered

Tags: swift, nstextfieldcell

I have a Table View Cell and have added an action to it that I want to execute when a value is changed.

[image]

I have added the action method in the viewController

```
@IBAction func valueEntered(sender: NSTextFieldCell)
{

    print("valueEntered")

}
```

I can edit the Table View Cell by double clicking on it, but my method is never called.

I know I have done this before but I must be missing a step.

Comment: Have you tried using the textfields delegate methods?

Comment: I am guessing that your `@IBAction` is conflicting with the tables delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Have you tried putting a breakpoint at the tableView's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`? Could you try putting up some codes so it is easier to narrow down the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to hook up the `NSTableView` delegate.

In your case, control-click and drag from `Reseller Table` up to `File's Owner` and choose `delegate`.